# How to know the curator version?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am using Elasticsearch version 2.1.0. How can I know the version of Curator being used ?
While changing the settings (number of replicas) I am getting an exception as:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason":Can't update [index.number_of_replicas] on closed indices [[.marvel-es-2016.12.12] - can leave index in an unopenable state"
"status": 400
}
```

Any clues ?

Comment: How is this error related to curator? curator version can be found when running- "curator --version"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get curator version by using the following command

```
$ curator --version
```

I think you are trying to set the replica to a indices which is in closed state.

Try setting replicas after opening the indices.

Related information can be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9566)